# Insert sum of rows and display it in the same table

Tags: sql-server

I have a table as shown below

[image]

I want to insert the row below each employee having data as like same employeecode, employeename, project as 'bench', expected end & start dates as null , install capacity as sum of all install capacities of that employees-184 and allocation % as null.

Result should look like this.

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME SELECT EMPLOYEEDODE, EMPLOYEENAME, 'BENCH' AS PROJECTNAME, NULL AS START_DT, NULL AS ENDDT, SUM(install_capacities), SUM(ActualPercentage)  FROM TABLE_NAME GROUP BY EMPLOYEEDODE,EMPLOYEENAME;
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. I am getting error like "Column 'TABLE_NAME .Employeename' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause."

Comment: Updated my query now check sorry I din included EMPLOYEENAME in group by;

Answer (score 1):

Please try the below queries to produce the desired output:

```
 insert into tbl(EmployeeCode, EmployeeName, projectName,ExpectedStartDate, ExpectedEndDate, InstallCapacity, [Actual Allocation Percentage])
    select  EmployeeCode,EmployeeName,'Bench' As projectName,NULL as ExpectedStartDate, NULL as ExpectedEndDate, SUM(InstallCapacity) as InstallCapacity, SUM([Actual Allocation Percentage]) as [Actual Allocation Percentage]
    from tbl
    group by EmployeeCode,EmployeeName

select * from tbl order by EmployeeCode,EmployeeName
```